# Sed and order patterns

Tags: regex, unix, sed

I have a file that containes my target lines (start with '>') ...

```
>lcl|1:c127-20 Ricardo3 phone
```

I want to get :

```
>Ricardo3:127-20
```

My steps: (1) Change ':' with ' ', (2) remove string 'c' and (3) get the first and second match and print them in different order separated by ':' as '\2[:]\1'.

This is my code:

```
sed -e '/^>/s/:/ /' -e '/^>/s/c//' -e '/^>/s/.*\s\([A-Z_0-9a-z]*\)\s.*\[A-Z_0-9a-z].*/\2[:]\1/' file
```

But I still get only:

```
>ll|1 127-20 Ricardo3 phone
```

I have a complicated time with regex in the last sed structure. Any help would be super useful.

Thanks

Comment: You need to provide more details about what the precise pattern is and which parts you need to extract. It's hard to extrapolate from just one example.

Comment: I am missing a second pair `()`, resulting in `sed: -e expression #3, char 55: invalid reference \2 on s' command's RHS`.
I see one expression to delete a `c` and two letters `c` are deleted, do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed -r 's/.*:c(\S*)\s+(\S*)\s.*/>\2:\1/' <<<">lcl|1:c127-20 Ricardo3 phone"
>Ricardo3:127-20
```

the above line works for given input. (gnu sed)

Comment: 'illegal option -- r ' . Stil without '-r', I got: \2 not defined in the RE

Comment: If that's BSD sed (or even modern GNU sed, but then `-r` should also work) you can use `-E` instead. If none work, you'll have to escape all the parenthesis and use `[[:space:]]` and `[^[:space:]]` instead of `\s` and `\S`

Comment: True, I read the problem about -r and \s or \S in Mac. Thank you so much for making it clear!

Comment: What does the '+' does after \s?